# How to convert varchar to Base64 with concat function in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to convert column values to Base64 encoding using concat function for an incremental load by using the following code

```
@if(
    contains(activity('ADS_Lookup').output,'firstRow'),
    concat(
        'select ID,POLICY_ASSET_ID,ASSET_CLAUSE_ID,ADDITIONAL_TEXT,UPDATE_USER,UPDATE_DATE,UPDATE_VERSION,CANCEL_DATE,CANCEL_USER,ACTIVE_REASON_TYPE_ID,ADDITIONAL_AMOUNT,CLAUSE_TEXT,CAST(N'' AS XML).value(''xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("CLAUSE_TEXT_BLOB")))' , 'VARCHAR(MAX)'') AS CLAUSE_TEXT_BLOB, BESPOKE_SUBJECT,CLAUSE_VERSION_ID,EXT_DATA,EXTRA_DATA_BLOB_ID from [',
        variables('schema'),
        '].[',
        if(variables('custom_table_list_flag'),item(),item().name),
        '] where update_date >=',
        '''',
        activity('ADS_Lookup').output.firstRow.startTime,
        ''''
    ),
    concat(
        'select ID,POLICY_ASSET_ID,ASSET_CLAUSE_ID,ADDITIONAL_TEXT,UPDATE_USER,UPDATE_DATE,UPDATE_VERSION,CANCEL_DATE,CANCEL_USER,ACTIVE_REASON_TYPE_ID,ADDITIONAL_AMOUNT,CLAUSE_TEXT,CAST(N'' AS XML).value(''xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("CLAUSE_TEXT_BLOB")))' , 'VARCHAR(MAX)'') AS CLAUSE_TEXT_BLOB, BESPOKE_SUBJECT,CLAUSE_VERSION_ID,EXT_DATA,EXTRA_DATA_BLOB_ID from [',
        variables('schema'),
        '].[',
        if(variables('custom_table_list_flag'),item(),item().name),
        ']'
    )
)
```

however I'm getting the following errors:

> Failure happened on 'Source' side.
> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A
> database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax
> near 'xs:'. The label 'xs' has already been declared. Label names must
> be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. Unclosed quotation
> mark after the character string
> ''.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect
> syntax near 'xs:'. The label 'xs' has already been declared. Label
> names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.,Source=.Net
> SqlClient Data
> Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect
> syntax near 'xs:'.,},{Class=15,Number=132,State=1,Message=The label
> 'xs' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a
> query batch or stored
> procedure.,},{Class=15,Number=105,State=1,Message=Unclosed quotation
> mark after the character string ''.,},]

Comment: Try to replace your existing `CAST` (twice) with this where I added a few quotations: `CAST(N'' AS XML).value(''xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("CLAUSE_TEXT_BLOB")))'', ''VARCHAR(MAX)'') AS CLAUSE_TEXT_BLOB`. Also consider using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead, as you use `N` for Unicode string.

Comment: Hi it's still giving the same error

Comment: @TANMAY SETHI, You will get a query from the above expression in the activity input. Can you provide that? or can you try executing that query in normal SQL and check if it results same or not?